# Convert methods to a generic method in DAO layer

Tags: java, generic-programming

Currently I'm having some methods in my DAO layer with multiple select queries. What I was thinking is to have a generic method for all these three methods so that it can be used for further also. Here are my methods.

```
public List<Customer> findAll(){

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER";

    List<Customer> customers  = getJdbcTemplate().query(sql,
        new BeanPropertyRowMapper(Customer.class));

    return customers;
}
```

For finding phone numbers of a customer.

```
public List<Phone> findPhoneNumbers(int custId){

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM PHONE WHERE CUST_ID="+custId;

    List<Phone> phoneNumbers  = getJdbcTemplate().query(sql,
        new BeanPropertyRowMapper(Phone.class));

    return phoneNumbers;
}
```

and so on.

Can these methods can be converted in a single generic method, so that it can be called from my service layer. Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your two methods have different parameters. You can have a single genetic method ```<T> List<T> findAll(String sql, Class<T> clazz) {...}```. But you will have to construct sql statement before calling the method.

Comment: @zhh, can you please reply in the answer with the elaboration where a single method will fit for these two methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public <T> List<T> findAll(String sql, Class<T> clazz) {
   return getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(clazz));
}
```

Then you call

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER";
List<Customer> customers = findAll(sql, Customer.class);
```

Or

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM PHONE WHERE CUST_ID="+custId;
List<Phone> phoneNumbers = findAll(sql, Phone.class);
```

The problem is that you have to construct sql statement before calling the method.

Maybe you want an android sqldatabase-like interface and construct sql statement in the method.

```
public <T> List<T> findAll(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy,  Class<T> clazz) {
    String sql = // construct sql statement
    return getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(clazz));
}
```

I'm not familiar with sql statement, you may find something in the Android SDK `SQLiteQueryBuilder.buildQueryString(...)`.

If you really want to return a single item not a list with one item, you need another method.

```
public <T> T findOne(String sql, Class<T> clazz) {
    // your sql statement should contains something like "limit 1"
    List<T> result = findAll(sql, clazz);
    return result.isEmpty() ? null : result.get(0);
}
```

If you need one method but you require to return `List<T>` for multiple data and `T` for single data. Try this:

```
public <T> Object findAll(String sql, Class<T> clazz, bool one) {
    List<T> all = getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(clazz));
    return one ? all.get(0) : all;
}
```

But I don't really suggest this approach. I don't think it is necessary to return a single item rather than a list with a single item.

Comment: zhh, in case if I want to have a single Row, like returning only Customer object instead of List<Customer>, how can I handle?

Comment: Just saw..Here again I need to have two methods like findAll and findOne with only one difference as "return result.isEmpty() ? null : result.get(0)";  we can still optimize the findAll method right?

Comment: Yes, ```findOne``` relies on ```findAll```.

Comment: So, should we use findOne or findAll? I wanted to use a single method for all my select queries instead of two methods.

Comment: See my updated answer. Why you have to return a single item rather than a list with single item?

Comment: Thx zhh.. Accepted your answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generic method and let the caller specify the class.

It's easy for `findAll`

```
public <T> List<T> findAll(Class<T> entityClass, String tableName){

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;

    return getJdbcTemplate().query(sql,
        new BeanPropertyRowMapper(entityClass));

    return phoneNumbers;
}
```

You can further improve this by using class metadata, such as specifying an annotations:

```
@Target(ElementType.Type)
public @interface MappedTable {
    String tableName();
}

//apply the annotation to bean classes:
@MappedTable(tableName="CUSTOMERS")
public class Customer {}
```

Which will allow your `findAll` method to look like:

```
public <T> List<T> findAll(Class<T> entityClass){

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + entityClass
      .getAnnotation(MappedTable.class).tableName();

    return getJdbcTemplate().query(sql,
        new BeanPropertyRowMapper(entityClass));

    return phoneNumbers;
}
```

Implementing `findByXyZ` will be trickier, but you can use a similar approach that either takes the full query from the caller or that uses additional annotation-based metadata.

**Note** that the complexity of this kind of code grows very fast. That's why it's a good idea to consider using ORM tools instead of reinventing them (the above is just an idea for simple cases as the one in the question).

Comment: Ernest, Im confused with "You can further improve this by using class metadata, such as specifying an annotations:".

Comment: @Syed I've edited to show the full method. The fact is that making the method generic has more implications than just the return type. You also need to change the table name being queried. There are many ways to handle this, one of which is taking the full query from the caller. For `findAll`, you can also just take the table name. Using an annotation that is used on entity classes can simplify the method by removing the `table name` parameter...

Comment: what if the case if I have select query with joins inside? I feel that its simple to have zhh answer to implement this.. to have SQL queries created before itself

Comment: @Syed Of course this can get very complex. That's why we should rather stick to well-established tools, like JPA/Hibernate, GORM, etc. But if you just want a simple way of making calls such as in your example, then that was just to give you an idea of how to approach it.

Comment: Because our application is not using either Hibernate or JPA.

Comment: @Syed I understand that. So you just have to be warned that trying to write code that does what Hibernate does is not trivial. If you find yourself dealing with such complexities, maybe you should reconsider your decision about using JPA/etc. or not.

Comment: I appreciate your ideas. But unfortunately I don't have the right to decide to go for any ORM technologies to get integrated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inheritance to achieve this

1) `class Customer`

2)`class PhoneNumber extends Customer`

3) `class Address extends Customer`

4) Declaring methods as

```
public List<T> findPhoneNumbers(Customer customer){ 
if(customer instanceOf PhoneNumber) {sql ="get phone number query ...."}
else if(customer instanceOf Address) {sql ="get address query ...."}
else {sql = get customer query}
}
```

Now in the calling method(ServiceLayer), you can pass appropriate object to choose query and get result

Comment: Ashish, this should be suitable for other types also. This is not a generic way, because there are some other classes where it is no where related to either Customer or PhoneNumber